# Running the same spider simultaniously

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.20 with python 2.7

I want to ask, what is the cons and pros of running the same spider twice in the same time?

Please know that I am using a pipeline in order to write the results to a json file.

Thanks

Comment: Multiple spiders crawling the same domain, or different domains?

Comment: @Talvalin the same spider ,the same domain

Answer (score 0):

The only application I see for running at the same time multiple instances of a spider is when each instance will have it's own part of `start_urls`. But each instance should be run on a different network interface, otherwise you cannot control effectively crawling intensity  for the same domain.